# A word that describes both (product) registration and (product) survey data

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A software product that I'm developing for a company has two sections, 'Registration' and 'Survey'.

**Registration** --
Similar to those postcards you (used to) find when you purchase a product:

- Name, Address, Email, Where product was purchased, etc.

**Survey** -- Most closely resembles [Net Promoter Score](https://www.netpromoter.com/know/):

- Recommendation (of product) score (scale from 0 to 10),
  Reason for recommendation score,
  Optional Contact Info (Name, Phone #, Email, etc.)

At times in internal documentation (meaning, their customers will not see this), I need to refer to both types of data and I would like to avoid having to use the specific phrase "survey and registration data" repeatedly.

Examples:
In the "survey and registration data" sections, ...
We send the survey and registration data to ...

I would like to be able to do something like:
The "survey and registration data" sections (hereby referred to as < insert word/phrase here > sections)...

**Question:

Is there a word or phrase that might summarize or generalize both types of data?**

Searching the internet, there were three possibilities that I considered (including synonyms), but none seemed to describe either or both.

- Market Research
  This is probably the closest that I could find, but not sure it accurately describes the 'Registration' section.
- Demographic
  Socioeconomic characteristics of a population expressed statistically, such as age, sex, education level, income level, marital status
  (from [businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/demographic-factors.html))
- Census
  A census is a collection of the demographic factors associated with every member of a population. (from same link as above)

Comment: What about just *Customer Data* sections

Comment: @Jim That could be a contender; however we do use/collect/interact with other data that we refer to as customer data, so it would be ambiguous. I decided to go with Market Research data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ultimately decided to group the two types under the term 'Market Research data'

Comment: You should accept this as the answer to your question.